# Can we create Azure Service Connection using any command/script/ARM Template?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, serviceconnection

I need to create Azure Service Connection, I can create the same using UI in Azure DevOps portal. But I need to know if I can create the same using some Az command or ARM Template or any Powershell script ?

Comment: can I use my existing Service Principal details to create new service connection using "az devops service-endpoint create" ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 ?
Here, You can manage Azure services using Azure REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can create service endpoint via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) or [Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/service_endpoint?view=azure-devops).

REST API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

Azure DevOps CLI:

```
az devops service-endpoint create
```

Comment: can I use my existing Service Principal details to create new service connection using "az devops service-endpoint create" ?

Comment: You can create service endpoint using configuration file, and capture network trace (using tool of your preference like Fiddler, Chrome Developer tool) of existing Service Principal details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/service_endpoint?view=azure-devops#create-service-endpoint-using-configuration-file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cece. Will check and confirm you.